# R and MySQL - checking if a row exists in a table before writing to it using dbWriteTable()

Tags: mysql, r

I am using the R packages RMySQL and dbConnect to connect my R with my Company's MySQL database. In short, my R script connects to the MySQL database, pulls one table (table1) from the database, uses that table to do some analyses, and then writes to another table (table2) in the MySQL database.

So table2 is not pulled from the database, but needs to be appended with the work I do in R.  adds to the table with some other analysis I've done in R, and then re-writes the table to the MySQL database, appending the previous one with the new information. The line of code that I currently use to write to table2 is:

```
dbWriteTable(con_hub, value = my_R_dataframe, name = "table2", append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
```

I need to make sure that there are no rows in my_R_dataframe that are already in the table2 database table before writing this, since duplicates are a pain to handle. Does anybody have any suggestions for this? Also - I would prefer not to have to pull table2 from the MySQL database into R, since that query would add a decent bit of time to my code.

Thanks,

Comment: cannot you add an index to table2 to with the constraint that entries must be unique?

Comment: yes, I could, just not sure how to implement that. there's a column in table2 that is unique and shouldn't be duplicated.

Answer (score 3):

Consider one of two ways: an SQL-driven de-dupe or R-driven de-dupe solution. For the former, you would need use of a temp, staging table that runs the classic [`LEFT JOIN...IS NULL/NOT EXISTS/NOT IN`](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) SQL query. For latter, you would import all content in a dataframe, append your current df, and run R's `unique()`. However, it sounds like you do not intend for latter but I show for future readers.

**SQL** *(using a temp table with exact structure of destination table)*

```
# OVERWRITE TEMP EACH TIME
dbWriteTable(con_hub, value = my_R_dataframe, 
                      name = "table2_temp", 
                      overwrite = TRUE,                        
                      row.names = FALSE)

# RUN LEFT JOIN...IS NULL QUERY (COMPARE COLS --COL1, COL2, COL3-- ADD/REMOVE AS NEEDED)
dbSendQuery(con_hub, paste0("INSERT INTO table2", 
                            " SELECT * FROM table2_temp",
                            " LEFT JOIN table2",
                            "   ON table2_temp.col1 = table2.col1", 
                            "   AND table2_temp.col2 = table2.col2",
                            "   AND table2_temp.col3 = table2.col3",
                            " WHERE table2.col1 IS NULL",
                            "   OR table2.col2 IS NULL",
                            "   OR table2.col3 IS NULL"))
```

**R** *(read in table2 data, consider if not too taxing on resources, preferred if de-duping by all columns)*

```
# RETRIEVE table2 DATA
table2df <- dbGetQuery(con_hub, "SELECT * FROM table2")

# APPEND BOTH DATAFRAMES
stackeddf <- rbind(table2df, my_R_dataframe)

# RETURN UNIQUE ROWS
finaldf <- unique(stackeddf)

# OVERWRITE DESTINATION TABLE EACH TIME
dbWriteTable(con_hub, value = finaldf, 
                      name = "table2", 
                      overwrite = TRUE,                         
                      row.names = FALSE)

# CLEAN UP ENVIRON OF UNNEEDED OBJECTS
rm(table2df, stackeddf, finaldf)
gc()
```