# How to avoid duplicates while appending R data frame to MYSQL DB

Tags: r

I have a data frame DF_1 in the MYSQL DB , Now i want to add DF_2 from Rstudio to DF_1 which is there in DB. for this I am using code as below

```
DF_1 <- data.frame("SN" = 1:3, "Age" = c(21,15,20), "Name" = c("John","Dora","Mike"))

DF_2 <- data.frame("SN" = 1:3, "Age" = c(21,15,30), "Name" = c("John","Dora","Clark"))

 dbWriteTable(connection, "df_1", DF_2,row.names=F,append=T)
```

But the above code writes duplicates in DB

Any modifications in the above code would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-a-mysql-table)

Comment: Thanks Akrun for your quick response.. Any modifications in the R code so that i can avoid duplicates before writing the data frame to DB.

Comment: I am assuming the DF_1 is not already created as object in the R env.  If it is, then `unique(rbind(DF_1, DF_2))` would do

Comment: Also check with `dbSendQuery`

Comment: Its(DF_1) already created as data frame and stored in DB, DF_2 is next set of data that i am trying to append to df_1 there in MYSQL DB

Comment: You may also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154234/r-and-mysql-checking-if-a-row-exists-in-a-table-before-writing-to-it-using-dbw)

Comment: Thank you very much Akrun , I have learn a new thing..I did it  "df_1 <- dbGetQuery(connection, "SELECT * FROM df_1")" .."df_1 <- rbindlist(list(df_1, DF_2), fill = TRUE)"...."df_1 <- unique(df_1)"...

Comment: finally dbWriteTable(connection, value = df_1, 
             name = "df_1", 
             overwrite = TRUE,                         
             row.names = FALSE)